# UIButton color changes by itself

Tags: ios, uibutton

I'm creating a button programmatically and adding it to UIScrollView:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(50, 10, 150, 80);
[button setTitle:@"all" forState:0];
button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Light" size:20];
button.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
button.layer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
[scrolView addSubview:newGuysButon];
```

When I click on the scroll view, button color changes from black to white. How could it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `– setTitleColor:forState:` to set your text color

Answer (score 0):

a custom button has a lot of states.  There are some default things that will happen, but if you want to absolutely specify everything then you need to also tell it what to do for each of the states. (normal, highlighted, selected, disabled)